# What is a good way of creating dialog in android in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I have a SettingsActivity.kt as follows:

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setLayout()
        setListeners()

    }

    private fun setLayout() {/* fun to set layout* /}
    private fun setListeners() {
        val day = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.settings_day)
        day.setOnClickListener { myDialog() }

        /* some other dialogs created in similar way */
    }

    private fun myDialog() {
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var selectedDay = prefs.getInt("day", 1)

        val myBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        myBuilder
            .setTitle(R.string.settings_day)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.days, selectedDay) { _, which ->
                selectedDay = which
            }
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok) { _, _ ->
                val editor = prefs.edit()
                editor
                    .putInt("day", selectedDay)
                    .apply()
            }
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel) { _, _ -> /* do nothing */ } 

        val theDialog = myBuilder.create()
        theDialog.show()
    }
}
```

When the orientation of device changes, the dialog disappears.

I think I have to use DialogFragment, but I have some problems,
the official guide at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#kotlin doesn't explain much. I am confused where to place the code.

Most of the tutorials on DialogFragment are either for custom layout or in java.

So, can somebody tell me how to convert my code
so as to use DialogFragment.
I am having difficulty to understand it from examples.

Comment: Of all this, what is *exactly* the problem you have? That your dialog disappears "when the orientation changes" or that you don't know how to show multiple dialogs? It's not clear if you're asking for one, the other, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `DialogFragment` and override `onCreateDialog()` to return your `AlertDialog`, e.g. just move your `myDialog` code up to `myBuilder.create()` there.

When you want do display your `DialogFragment`, instantiate it and call show on it, passing in a reference to the fragment manager and an (optional) tag. For example:

```
MyDialogFragment().show(requireFragmentManager(), null)
```

Comment: can you explain in more detail, I am a student and new to android development, most of things you're saying I can't understand.

Comment: The doc you linked https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#kotlin has this concept in more detail

Comment: Why I am a finding it very difficult to understand? I can understand what's going in the function, but I don't understand from where to call what and where it is returned? Any video tutorial in kotlin would be helpful?

Comment: do I have to create a new dialog.kt file for each dialog?

Comment: is requireFragmentManager() actually something? Android Studio shows red line below it

Comment: Depends where your code is. Anyway it's an example how to obtain a nonnull FragmentManager. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#requireFragmentManager()

Comment: requireFragmentManager is showing compilation error? But replacing it with this@SettingsActivity.supportFragmentManager worked.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Anko is now deprecated, please [read this](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md).**

If you're working with Kotlin, the [Anko Library](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) may interest you. It provides an easy way to create Alerts, Dialogs, and other common tasks.

> Anko is a Kotlin library which makes Android application development faster and easier. It makes your code clean and easy to read, and lets you forget about rough edges of the Android SDK for Java.

### 1- Adding Anko to your project

To add Anko to you Android Kotlin project, add the dependency to your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
}
```

(If you only want to use it for creating Dialogs, just add anko-commons) :

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
```

Make sure that you have the $anko_version variable in your gradle file at the project level:

```
ext.anko_version='0.10.8'
```

### 2- Using Anko to create an Alert/Dialog

A simple example:

```
alert { title = "Your Title goes here!"

        customView {
            val nameInput = editText() {hint = "Name?"}

            positiveButton("OK!") {
                if( checkUser(nameInput.text) ) {
                  sayHelloTo(nameInput.text)
                }
            }

            negativeButton("ABORT!") { /* do nothing */ }
        }

  }.show()
```

**Please read [Anko Documentation - Dialogs](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Dialogs) to learn how to use Anko.**